# OnManualSubmit как определить index

Tags: qt

Таблица.

```
  setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit);  
  ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

`model->submitAll();` по нажатию на кнопку(QPushButton). Как перед сабмитом  проверить, если в комбобоксе было выбрано значение "cancel", то выполнить определенное действие...

Answer (score 0):

А где у вас комбобокс?

```
QComboBox* ComboBox = new QComboBox();
```

Вообще узнать текущий индекс можно так:

```
ComboBox->currentIndex(); // вернет int
```

Можно у комбобокса спросить, какой он отображает текст:

```
ComboBox->currentText(); // вернет QString с тем текстом, который выбран
```

Comment: ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(model->fieldIndex("status_name"),new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui->tableView)); //для комбобокса со статусом заказа

Comment: То, что задано с помощью `setItemDelegate()` можно получить `itemDelegate()`